# creating thumbnails without saving them

Tags: php, thumbnails

I need to create a page that will automatically create a thumbnail from all images if selected folder and show them on the same page. But the thing is, I don't want to save them. I want to display them on the same page without saving. And I need to do that in PHP. Is it possible? Please help!
Note: If that is not possible,I can put them in some folder.

Comment: You can do that, but it's usually a really bad idea for your server load.

Comment: Unless you are using something like CSS or HTML parameters for the images... I believe you will be saving those thumbnails, regardless, (if even to the /tmp folder or somewhere...) when using PHP.

Comment: Do you have a link to some example?

Comment: What images you want to use as a thumbnail?

Comment: @ceejayoz Of course creating thumbnails on the fly will create additional server load, but it may be worth it. It all depends on how much space is available for storage, how much load is on the server already, and how the thumbnails will be used. Maybe the best of both worlds approach would be to create the thumbnails on the fly, but save them to a temporary cached directory that gets cleaned out every day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a second PHP-file then. You have to make an image tag in the first file `<img src='image.php' />` and in this image.php you have to print out the image like:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$im     = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($im);
$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, "100", "100", $width, $height);

imagepng($newimage);
imagedestroy($newimage);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: This, plus look into the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function.

Comment: Correct, I forgot that this has to be a thumbnail. I'll update the code above.

Comment: How can I do this for more then one image?
Should I create an array of images?

Comment: Then you have to make more <img> tags and link to this php file. But this has to be dynamic if you don't want the same image a few times..

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).  Use the code in DRP96's answer to create the thumbnail, but instead of doing it in a separate PHP and requiring many image requests, embed the images directly on the page.

Most modern browsers support data URIs now, but as usual, watch out for IE.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($im);
```

with this

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("image.png");
```