# create thumbnails without saving them

Tags: php

I have this code which creates thumbnails and then prints them on the website without storing them somewhere.

```
<img src ="imageThumbnail.php" alt="some description"/>
```

this works fine when i did this and it did show me the output.

`imageThumbnail.php`

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$im     = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($im);
$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, "100", "100", $width, $height);

imagepng($newimage);
imagedestroy($newimage);
imagedestroy($im);
```

This code was taken from here [creating thumbnails without saving them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841714/creating-thumbnails-without-saving-them)

Now what i wanted was that to send some data to this `imageThumbnail` php file and then make a query to the database and get the correct path for the particular data that has been passed as get but the ouput was not as expected and the image doesn't show up.

`Html code`

```
  <img src ="imageThumbnail.php?product_code=PD1001" alt="some description"/>
```

`imageThumbnail.php`   `This is the modified code`

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$productCode=$_GET['product_code'];
require 'connect.inc.php';
$statement=$mysqli->prepare("select `product_img_name` from `products` where `product_code`=?");
$statement->bind_param("s",$productCode);
$statement->execute();
$result=$statement->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_object())
    $pathName=$row->product_img_name;

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg("cart/images/".$pathName);
$width=imagesx($im);
$height=imagesy($im);
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor(116,116);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0,'116', '116', $width, $height);
imagejpeg($newimage);
imagedestroy($newimage);
imagedestroy($im);
```

What is the problem and how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Do we really need all of that code to answer your question?

Comment: Yeah i think all of this is important and related to my question. @m02ph3u5

Comment: @m02ph3u5 updated my question with much less code

Comment: Try to echo all your variables to check if everything is OK, specially the path that you make for your main image.

Comment: Yes i did use the chrome logger to check this and everything is fiine @AliFarhoudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that require file in the code and instead use the whole code.

`Something like this`

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$productCode=$_GET['product_code'];
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$host_name = "localhost";
$db_name = 'cakenbake';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$statement=$mysqli->prepare("select `product_img_name` from `products` where `product_code`=?");
$statement->bind_param("s",$productCode);
if($statement->execute())
{
    $result=$statement->get_result();
    while($row=$result->fetch_object())
        $pathName=$row->product_img_name;
    $im=imagecreatefromjpeg("cart/images/".$pathName);
    $width=imagesx($im);
    $height=imagesy($im);
    $newimage=imagecreatetruecolor(116,116);
    imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0,'116', '116', $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($newimage);
    imagedestroy($newimage);
    imagedestroy($im);
}



?>
```

Use this code .This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
require 'connect.inc.php';

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$productCode=$_GET['product_code'];

$statement=$mysqli->prepare("select `product_img_name` from `products` where `product_code`=?");
$statement->bind_param("s",$productCode);
$statement->execute();
$result=$statement->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_object())
    $pathName=$row->product_img_name;

$im=imagecreatefromjpeg("cart/images/".$pathName);
$width=imagesx($im);
$height=imagesy($im);
$newimage=imagecreatetruecolor(116,116);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0,'116', '116', $width, $height);
imagejpeg($newimage);
imagedestroy($newimage);
imagedestroy($im);
```